# How to set path of your dll file in post-build event for visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, post-build

I have a .net application (Class Library). I want to run this command "editbin /largeaddressaware "$(TargetPath)"
" in post build event.Can anyone tell me how to give MyFile.dll path in target dir.

Comment: That's not sensible, a C# library project already generates a DLL that is LAA with default project settings.  Focus on the problem you are trying to solve instead of the perceived solution.

Comment: @HansPassant there are some scenarios in which LAA is disabled due to some compilation reasons. I solved my issue now. Thanks by the way.